# trigger/mimick click even on DOM ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ahve this jQuery that is called on click,

```
$("#overflow-cntr img").click(function(){
            $this = $(this);
            $("#bigpic-cntr canvas").remove();  
            $("#bigpic-cntr #bigpic").css("display", "block");
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                EFFECTS[$this.attr("id")]();
                }, 30);
        });
```

How would I trigger this on DOM ready instead of on click?

Comment: instead of or in addition to?

Comment: In case my question was unclear: do you still want to trigger that event on click, or do you really want to trigger it on DOM ready *instead* of on click.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? We never heard anything after the original question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // bind the event and then trigger it immediately
    $("#overflow-cntr img").click(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $("#bigpic-cntr canvas").remove();  
        $("#bigpic-cntr #bigpic").css("display", "block");
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            EFFECTS[$this.attr("id")]();
            }, 30);
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: this answer is best if you want to trigger the function both on page load and on click. if you just want to trigger the event on page load and not on click, all you need is $(document).ready. +1

Comment: @DougieBear Thanks for the comment and upvote. I saw your edit, but in my case, it would be incorrect to change `$(this)` to `$("#overflow-cntr img")` because there could be multiple `img`'s in `#overflow-cntr` and I need to target the one that was clicked. Now that I think of it, that makes your answer a little off. I'll comment below your answer.

Comment: sorry about the edit, I meant to edit my answer but accidentally clicked on yours and now realize why mine didn't update the first time >_<

Answer (score 0):

Place the function inside $(document).ready() instead of click():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $this = $("#overflow-cntr img");
        $("#bigpic-cntr canvas").remove();  
        $("#bigpic-cntr #bigpic").css("display", "block");
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            EFFECTS[$this.attr("id")]();
            }, 30);
});
```

Comment: but then `$(this)` wouldn't be the `$("#overflow-cntr img")`

Comment: Instead of setting `$this = $('#overflow-cntr img')`, you actually need to loop through each `$('#overflow-cntr img')` and set `$this = $(this)`. Otherwise, `$this` would be all `img`'s inside of `#overflow-cntr`.